# Login with Cognito credentials in Node.js and calling the API gateway

Tags: javascript, node.js, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, amazon-cognito

So I've been at this for quite some time, and I'm still feeling like I'm just running circles around myself :)

I have an API gateway on AWS that uses a user pool as its authorizer.
I know AWS-Amplify, since I use it for my React frontend part, but I can't seem to find an elegant way to login with Cognito credentials in node.js.

I tried using [this library](https://www.npmjs.com/package/amazon-cognito-identity-js-node) which is a fork of the somewhat deprecated amazon-cognito-identity-js, AWS-Amplify's precursor.

It allows me to use the `.authenticateUser` method and returns three tokens:

- Cognito id token
- Cognito refresh token
- Cognito access token

Next I tried to use axios (doesn't really matter I guess), to make a simple `GET` request with the Authorization header set to the `idToken` I got before.

This token works while testing the authorizer on the API Gateway console, but it doesn't work from node...

The error returned is:

> Authorization header requires \'Credential\' parameter. Authorization header requires \'Signature\' parameter. Authorization header requires \'SignedHeaders\' parameter. Authorization header requires existence of either a \'X-Amz-Date\' or a \'Date\' header.

So I tried signing the request with aws4 which also didn't help, it returned an error which said their signature doesn't match mine and to check my secretAccessKey...

Is it really this complicated? I just wanted to write a simple PoC app that tests my lambda API, this all seems like too much work for something so simple...

Comment: What are you trying to do exactly? What’s your setup? I think I can help, but I need to know more about your process/setup.